# how to make mysql query like this situation?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database table which struction is:

```
startphoneNum      |   endphoneNum      |   department
022589893232011    |   022589893232021  |   sales
022589893232027    |   022589893232029  |   Human Resources
022589893232041    |   022589893232048  |   after sales
```

the phone number is made by 3 parts: 022(city code)- 589893232(company number) - 011(extension number)

I could use php explode, make a phone number from the format `022-589893232-011` to `022589893232011`, then how to put `phone number` via a `mysql query` to get the `department name`?

For example:

If I put a phone number `022589893232043`, it belongs to `after sales`,
But how to make a `php mysql query` in code? and get the result what I need? Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try a query? If so please paste here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a BETWEEN query like this:

```
SELECT department FROM table WHERE '022589893232043' BETWEEN startphoneNum AND endphoneNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT department 
FROM table1 
WHERE startphoneNum >= PHP_VARIABLE AND endphoneNum <= PHP_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
$query = "SELECT department
          FROM myTable
          WHERE '$phoneNbr' BETWEEN startphoneNum AND endphoneNum;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT department FROM your_table
WHERE LEFT(your_num, 12) = LEFT(startphoneNum, 12)
  AND CONVERT(RIGHT(your_num, 3), UNSIGNED) BETWEEN
      CONVERT(RIGHT(startphoneNum, 3), UNSIGNED) AND
      CONVERT(RIGHT(endphoneNum, 3), UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select department from [table] where [phone number] > startphonenum AND [phonenumber] < endphonenum
```

replace []'s with actual values...

Answer (score 0):

select dp.department_name from department dp, phonenumber_table pn where pn.startphonenum > 'values' and pn.endphonenum < 'values